# SearchBox that filters a ListView while typing - is there a name for this component/pattern?

Tags: search, lists, filter, real-time-updates

In the desktop application I am developing, we have ListViews representing items in repositories, and for each one we have a TextBox at the top which works as a search box that filters elements in realtime.

I want to know if this is a **well-known pattern having a specific name**, so that I can research for best UX practices for that.

Note: this is not quite an "Autocomplete" Search Box, that suggests items as a drop-down list as you type. The intention here is to filter an existing list, with previously visible elements, as you type.

Comment: This is not unheard of, although I'm struggling to think of examples, I have seen this elsewhere.

It's hard to say whether it's good practice without knowing your information architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smashing Magazine terms these ['Dynamic Search' or 'Dynamic Filtering'](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/ui-patterns-for-mobile-apps-search-sort-filter/). While excellent terms, I'd argue they are still not quite the convention (so it may not help much as a research lead). Yet, I believe that upon hearing "*a list that can be dynamically searched*", most UXers will infer exactly what your'e after.

It is perhaps worth noting that technically a data set can be filtered in many ways (active, new, from Amazon sellers only), so if you want to be ultra specific you may use "*dynamic search query filter*", possibly dropping either '*search*' or '*query*'.

---

(Edited by OP) In the context of the question, the most appliable pattern of the linked article is "Dynamic Search", described as:

> Entering text in the search field will **dynamically (onkeypress) filter the data on the screen**.
>
> The dynamic search pattern is used to refine or whittle down a **existing and visible list of objects**.
>
> In the [examples, the displayed result items] **were already displayed on the page**.
>
> Works well for **refining constrained data sets**, like an address book or personal media library

Comment: A filter typically iterates on each item of an existing data set, keeping items that match a predicate. Search suggests a more complex algorithm on a large data set; such algorithm typically uses indexes and optimisations like binary search. Efficient search depends on data representation and additional operations during write. Filtering, on the other hand, is a rather straight forward iteration performed at query time (reads).

Comment: I accepted the answer after having mistakenly accepting the other. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, my first comment is also misplaced - it should be in the other answer... Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly this would probably either be "Auto Suggest" or "Instant Results" as described in this article "[Designing Search: As-You-Type Suggestions](https://uxmag.com/articles/designing-search-as-you-type-suggestions)"

Comment: That's a very handy reference despite the fact that it doesn't cover the exact use case here

Comment: @J.Dimeo actually it does (see my edit in the answer). As to how to name the component, I believe "DynamicSearch" is acceptable, or in the context of WPF which is my target platform, perhaps "DynamicSearchableListView" or something like that.

Comment: @heltonbiker not trying to be difficult, I'm honestly confused. I don't see the word "dynamic" or any of the text you quoted in the linked article.

Comment: Oh! it's from @Izhaki's answer. Perhaps you edited and accepted the wrong one?

Comment: Oh no! I see – looks like the OP has marked my answer although it should have been @Izhaki's answer… :/ Well – while of course I feel flattered, please do consider to re-place the 'best' check mark – if technically possible…

Comment: Right, folks, I corrected the mistake, thanks a lot for the honesty! ;o)

Comment: Also, I had posted the following comment there that was intended here: "Thanks for your answer! From the three patterns mentioned in the linked article (auto-complete, auto-suggest, instant results) I guess the one more directly related to my need is the last one: instant-results, that is, "as you type" results. As others have mentioned, "searching" is in principle considered different than "filtering", while upon second thought they are essentially, in most cases, a WHERE operator (as in SQL/LINQ) or FILTER operation (as in functional "filter/map/reduce" sort of operations)"

Answer (score 2):

The two words most associated with this are in your title- "**filter**" and "**list**". I've seen "List Filter" or "Filtered List" or "Filter List by Searching" in addition to the more "Auto Complete" or "Auto Suggest" type wording.

Here's an example of a JS lib that offers "filtering" on lists: http://listjs.com/overview/

I also implemented this in a desktop app (a medical records system) that filters the list of treatments (medicines) based on what the user types:
[image: MRS screenshot]

Do you have specific implementation or usability questions pertaining to this kind of widget?